# How to get whole dict with max value of a common key in a list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dicts like below:

```
lod = [
{'name': 'Tom', 'score': 60},
{'name': 'Tim', 'score': 70},
{'name': 'Tam', 'score': 80},
{'name': 'Tem', 'score': 90}
]
```

I want to get `{'name': 'Tem', 'score':90}` but I only can do below:

```
max(x['score'] for x in lod)
```

This only return the value `90`.

How can I get the whole dict?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [key function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-key-function) of `max`:

```
>>> lod = [
... {'name': 'Tom', 'score': 60},
... {'name': 'Tim', 'score': 70},
... {'name': 'Tam', 'score': 80},
... {'name': 'Tem', 'score': 90}
... ]
... 
>>> max(lod, key=lambda x: x['score'])
{'name': 'Tem', 'score': 90}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just pass your list to `max`, like this:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> lod = [
... {'name': 'Tom', 'score': 60},
... {'name': 'Tim', 'score': 70},
... {'name': 'Tam', 'score': 80},
... {'name': 'Tem', 'score': 90}
... ]
>>> max(lod, key=itemgetter('score'))
{'score': 90, 'name': 'Tem'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether `sorting` is time consuming,

```
>>>sorted(lod, key=lambda x:x['score'])[-1]
{'name': 'Tem', 'score': 90}
```